# How can I have my C code read and display multiple lines from a C file?

Tags: c

I am trying my best to have the code read multiple lines of texts from a text file. A sample output of what the text file contains is shown below (the first is studentID, second is gpa, third is initials):

```
12345 3.50000 aj
34286 4.10000 be
```

I only need the screen to display to me the studentID and the gpa. I have gotten it to display the first line of code, but not the rest of the code. My code is as follows:

```
void displayStudentGpas(FILE* inFile){
    int studentID;
    double gpa;
    char pipe = '|';
    
    while(fscanf(inFile, "%d %lf", &studentID, &gpa) == 2){
        printf("||%11d%4c%11.2lf%8c| \n", studentID, pipe, gpa, pipe);
        printf("||--------------|---------------------|| \n);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help you could give me... thank you!

Comment: You must read all characters from the input, Currently you only read id and gpa

Comment: Never use any kind of scanf() without checking the return value. Also have a look here http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html If that does not help please describe the ways you tried to apply the concepts described here and the results of your attempts to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I have tried using the scanf on a different function, I know how to use it, this is to display some items to the screen. When displaying initials through a very similar function, it works fine, it just is not working very well on the GPA one. I am having trouble executing this command for every line in the .txt file

Comment: fscanf does not automatically move to the next integer or float value. You'll still have to scan the string or use pointer manipulations to increment the file pointer until the next integer

Comment: I figured it out,I need to have this: "%d %lf %*c %*c" in my fscanf so that I can skip over the initials and move on to the next line

Comment: Or just use a %*s

Comment: Better, use `fgets()` to read the entire line into a sufficiently sized buffer (Don't *skimp* on buffer size) and then use `sscanf()` to parse what you need from the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In C, whenever you need to read a *line-at-a-time*, you use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. That way you consume the entire line of input and you do not leave a partial line unread.

In your case you attempt to use a *formatted-input* function `fscanf()` with the `"%d %lf"` format string. (but Good Job! on checking the return!). What happens when you attempt to read:

```
12345 3.50000 aj
```

is that `12345 3.50000` is read from the line leaving `"aj\n"` in the input buffer -- unread. Then on your next iteration your attempt to read again with `"%d %lf"` and a *matching failure* occurs because `"aj"` is not valid *integer* input.

When a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction ceases leaving `"aj"` in the input buffer unread -- again. But since you correctly check the return and condition your read loop on the successful read of both values -- your loop terminates instead of spinning off into an infinite loop attempting to read `"aj"` over-and-over again.

(**note:** your third-category of input functions are *character-oriented* functions such as `getchar()` or `fgetc()` or `getc()`)

The solution is simple. Use `fgets()` and a sufficiently sized buffer (*don't skimp on size*) to read the entire line and then use `sscnaf()` to parse all (or only the first two) values from the buffer and output the studentID and gpa. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXI 8

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold entire line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {                     /* read each line */
        int id;         /* ID */
        double gpa;     /* GPA */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d %lf", &id, &gpa) == 2)     /* parse id & gpa from buf */
            printf ("%-8d %5.1f\n", id, gpa);           /* on success -- output */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

(**note:** the program will read from the filename passed as the first argument to the program, or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided -- the way many Linux utilities do)

If you are on an embedded system with limited memory, you can adjust `MAXC` accordingly. (say `32` would be a nice power-of-two and still provide a 15-char margin)

**Example Use/Output**

Simply passing your example input in `stdin`, you would receive:

```
$ cat << eof | ./bin/studentidgpa
> 12345 3.50000 aj
> 34286 4.10000 be
> eof
12345      3.5
34286      4.1
```

To read values from a filename, you would use:

```
$ ./bin/studentidgpa filetoread
```

Or if you like, you can redirect `filetoread` on `stdin`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/studentidgpa < filetoread
```

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.

Answer (score -1):

This would be my solution to your problem in cpp, please let me know if I should convert it to c for you:

```cpp
#define studentCount 2
 //change if you have more than 2 students
void printStudents(std::string FILENAME) {
    std::ifstream file(FILENAME);

    int studentID[studentCount];
    double gpa[studentCount];
    std::string name[studentCount];

    std::string line; //tmp variable to store a line
    if (file.is_open()) {
        int i = 0;//Counter to keep track of the current student
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            int a = 0;//Counter to keep track of the current student data
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            while (getline(ss, line, ' ')) { //Split line by ' ' and store in line

                switch (a)
                {
                case 0:
                    studentID[i] = std::stoi(line); //Convert string to int
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gpa[i] = std::stod(line); //Convert string to double
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name[i] = line; //Nothing :(
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                a++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
        std::cout << "ID: " << studentID[i] << " | gpa:" << gpa[i] << " | Name: " << name[i] << "\n";
        std::cout << "||--------------|---------------------|| \n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::string FILENAME = "test.txt";

    printStudents(FILENAME);
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking about C, not C++